# Resampling data with mode gives empty lists... Need to convert those empty lists to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I resample data(indexed on DateTime) using mode, I get certain values as empty lists. I need to replace those empty list ('[]') values as 0s

Resampling data:

```py
dataframe = data.resample('10min').apply({'data':lambda x: x.mode(dropna = False)})
```

I tried:

```py
dataframe['mode'] = dataframe['mode'].applymap(lambda x: 0 if len(x) == 0 else x)
```

```
ACTUAL RESULT:
=============
date      mode<br>
---
11:00     1 <br>
11:10     2 <br>
11:20     [] <br>
11:30     [] <br>
```

```
REQUIRED RESULT:
=============
date      mode<br>
----
11:00     1 <br>
11:10     2 <br>
11:20     0 <br>
11:30     0 <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use isinstance instead of len because you'll run into errors with it being mixed list/integer types in the df.

try:

```
df['mode'] = df['mode'].apply(lambda x: 0 if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```

Comment: Thank you Anna for your answer.I tried this way but unfortunately it is still not working.... Now I am resampling first using 1 minute granularity and then resampling again for 10 mins using Mode. It is the only solution I can come up with right now